# Non-geometer friendly definition of $\cos$ and $\sin$.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, definition

Let $S=\{(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2: x^2+y^2=1\}$ be the unit circle.

From here, I want to define the $\sin$ and $\cos$ functions.

I've seen some sites saying things like

> "$\cos\theta$ is the $x$ coordinate of the point $P$ where a ray from the origin hits the unit circle, when making an angle $\theta$ with the $x$-axis."

This doesn't really satisfy me: What's an angle? After answering that, aren't there two directions for $\theta$ (i.e the upper half plane and the lower half plane)?

Could anyone help me define these trigonometric functions, purely using the unit circle, and making explicit which assumptions you're making.

E: Also, in many of these definition I've read, it's not clear to me why $\cos,\sin$ are determined for every $\theta\in \Bbb R$: Say we use definition above for $\theta\in [0,2\pi)$, and extend via periodicity.

What part says that given whatever $\theta\in [0,2\pi)$ we can trace a line from $0$, with this angle from the $x$-axis and it will hit the unit circle?

Comment: Angle is the ratio between the arc and the radius. It is generally ACW.

Comment: @HenryW. What is ACW?

Comment: Counterclockwise. (Or anticlockwise)

Comment: Of course, that requires defining the length of an arc, which is not so easy without calculus.

Comment: @RobertIsrael The OP asks for "layman's terms" so I think it's OK to assume arclength.

Comment: Well, my point is being able to start from this definition to prove it's equivalence with the power series definition. So I wanted to start assuming pretty much nothing (defining what's needed from a 'geometric'  point of view). How would you define arc length this way?

Comment: In "layman's" terms or in "geometer's"?  Or maybe "calculus student's"?

Comment: @RobertIsrael Maybe basic geometry terms would be better? :-P

Comment: The circumference of a circle of radius $1$ has length $2\pi$.  If you divide the circle into $m$ equal parts, each has arc length $2\pi/m$.  A length of an  irrational multiple of $2\pi$ can be obtained as a limit of rational multiples of $2\pi$.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine a particle traveling counterclockwise around the unit circle at a rate of one unit per second, starting at the point $(1,0)$. Then at time $\theta$ its at point $(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$. You can define the angle traversed as $\theta$ radians.

I recommend you learn more geometry. It's fun and will make you a better math student. Then change your stackexchange handle.